# How to wrap a div around sibling div

Tags: css

I would like to wrap a text div around its sibling image div.  Not to be confused with the standard way to wrap text around an image, but with two separate divs.
The example is below:

```
<div style="width:1000px;">
    <div>
        <img src="some url" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some very long text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make it look like the text is wrapping around the image.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think we need a diagram to understand your desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Float the div containing the image left or right.

```
<div style="width:1000px;">
    <div style="float:left">
        <img src="some url" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some very long text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JZdeC/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sux2Z/

```
<div>
    <img src="http://cdn.memegenerator.net/images/80x80/1167066.jpg" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, bibendum at, posuere sit amet, nibh. Duis tincidunt lectus quis dui viverra vestibulum. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui. Nulla elementum dui ut augue. Aliquam vehicula mi at mauris. Maecenas placerat, nisl at consequat rhoncus, sem nunc gravida justo, quis eleifend arcu velit quis lacus. Morbi magna magna, tincidunt a, mattis non, imperdiet vitae, tellus. Sed odio est, auctor ac, sollicitudin in, consequat vitae, orci. Fusce id felis. Vivamus sollicitudin metus eget eros.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. Pellentesque faucibus.
</div>

.div {width:400px;}
img {
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    float:left;
}
```